# Unbiased estimator of $\mu\ 'S^{-1} \mu$

Tags: multivariate-analysis, expected-value, unbiased-estimator

> $\vec X_1,\cdots ,\vec X_n$ are **iid** $N_2(\mu,\Sigma)$. Find an *unbiased estimator* of $\mu\ 'S^{-1} \mu$ as a linear function of its *mle*.

My work:

MLE is $\bar X\ 'S^{-1} \bar X$

Now

$$E(\bar X\ 'S^{-1} \bar X)=E(tr(\bar X\ 'S^{-1} \bar X))\\=tr(E(\bar X\ 'S^{-1} \bar X))\\=tr(E(S^{-1}\bar X\ '\bar X))\\=tr(E(S^{-1})E(\bar X\ '\bar X))$$

The last equation is because of the fact that $S$ and $\bar X\ ' \bar X$ are known to be independent.

I know $E(\bar X\ '\bar X)={\Sigma\over n}+\mu'\mu$

But I am not being able to find $E(S^{-1})$. Can someone help me proceed?